# Can you chain a USB hub off a USB port on a Thunderbolt display?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I'm considering getting a display with thunderbolt connection, to use as extra screen space and as docking station (on a macbook pro 2012)

Right now I'm using a USB hub for all the peripheral devices (music keyboard, soundcard, external harddrive, printer etc.)

If I plug that usb hub into the usb port on the display (or directly, without the hub), will it all function as it did before?

Comment: Does the hub have an external power supply?

Comment: @user3623501 Yes it does

Comment: I think you should be fine, the only issues I've had with daisy chaining USB hubs on my Apple monitor was lack of power resulting in erratic device behavior(mostly momentary disconnects and then reconnects).

Comment: Ok, thanks. If it doesn't work after all, I just plug the hub into the computer instead. But I also think it will ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Thunderbolt Display USB ports work well to connect a hub for more downstream devices. There is also enough power for unpowered hubs to connect low power devices like mice and USB flash storage. You will want a powered hub if you have multiple spinning hard drives or devices that you wish to charge from the hub itself.